# Can I run chkdsk for different HDDs at the same time (external via USB)?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, chkdsk, parallel-processing

I want to run multiple chkdsk commands (for different HDDs)
at the same time. 
All of them are external via USB.
I searched for this on Google, but there were few results
that were really relevant to my question,
and there I couldn’t understand what the person meant.

I don’t know programming, so it would be appreciated if you make the answer sweet and simple to understand.

I need to chkdsk multiple disks for used 6 TB NAS HDDs. 
I am intending to sell (few dozens)
and the buyers want their drives as early as possible.

I have a 4-bay HDD enclosure connected to PC via USB 3.0.

Is it possible to perform complete `chkdsk /f /r /x` tests on four drives at the same time?

Will that affect the quality of the test?  (I gave my buyers a generous warranty time and actually want them to have the product as long as possible.)

I didn’t do it yet but I am testing a single drive at the moment and it takes 10 hours to complete (thought it would be 3 hours max!!), that means a lot of days, and I can’t afford that.

Comment: You can only test as fast as the drive and the interface can go. It’s pretty simple math. 6TB is a big drive to test. It’s going to take many hours, per drive, no matter what you do. You can test multiple drives at once, but if they are all plugged in using the same interface they’re all just going to run at a fraction of the speed. Your best option is to hook them up directly to multiple SATA ports or even to multiple computers. Forget USB 3.

Comment: Yes you can, just open multiple instances of the command prompt and run chkdsk for each drive letter.